# Structuremap, AutoFac, or Ninject, which one is great for a large scale web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, structuremap, autofac

I have some experience in working by *`Structuremap`*. And now I'm creating a big and large scale web app (really a social networking site) using *`ASP.NET MVC 3`*, *`Entity Framework 4.1 code-first`*, *`SqlServer 2008`*, via *`C#.NET 4`*. Which one of *`Structuremap`*, *`AutoFac`*, and *`Ninject`* would you suggest me to use in this case? Performance and easy-of-use is important. Thanks to any help, idea and suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think there is no differences between them! Its associated on your-self. Every body has some favorites, and you too. I use `StructureMap` and its good enough for large and/or small scale applications.

**UPDATE:**

Well, a few months ago I met with [Simple Injector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/) which is really really simple, and actually fast. I've used it in several projects with different scales, and it really works perfectly.

Comment: Simple injector is good...but with [push-developers-into-best-practices](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/principles.html#push-developers-into-best-practices). It requires you to go for best practices in many cases. This might be a good point to a new project(for example, you are only allowed to have one public constructor), but it can be hard to adapt to existing projects that don't follow those practices.

Answer (score 55):

This article has a good summary of most popular IoC frameworks and discusses their performance as well as ease of use. All in all a great read!

http://philipm.at/2011/di_speed.html

& a follow-up at http://philipm.at/2011/di_speed_redux.html

Comment: +1 A good and perfect article. So thanks

Comment: it is a good article, but beware of the unity comments from an invalid test.

Comment: Additional post about IoC framework performance http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison with benchmark code at GitHub https://github.com/danielpalme/IocPerformance

Comment: It seems to me that the follow-up is even more important than the first article.

Answer (score 11):

If you are interested in HOW they are used in large scale web apps, one good one to look at is OrchardCMS; it uses Autofac.

Comment: NopCommerce is a widely used (very scalable, used for some very large installations) open-source e-commerce engine that uses Autofac as well (it recently moved off of Unity).

Answer (score 3):

I've only really looked at / used Ninject and simply haven't bothered looking at any others. The simplicity in usage & it's low learning curve fit my last couple of projects very well. IMO, it is a great IoC container for projects large and small.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Unity (some time ago), AutoFac and StructureMap and prefer StructureMap, specifically for its `AssertConfigurationIsValid` method which I use in unit tests to, well, assert that my StructureMap configuration is valid (relevant if you're using constructor-based DI).

As far as I'm aware only StructureMap offers this facility.

When using ASP.NET MVC, I also like how the StructureMap NuGet package wires things up for you nicely.